# PHP internal implementation of === operator for strings

Tags: php

I'm looking for implementation of strings comparison in PHP ($string === $string2).
I tried to search in [php-src](https://github.com/php/php-src), but nothing found. Any advice how to find this implementation or other php internal implementations? For Example in_array function is also interesting.

Comment: Why do you think `===` will be interesting? It just compares the characters.

Comment: `in_array` is also likely to be trivial. It's just a loop that compares each array element with the item.

Comment: those functions should be O(n). But I want to to make sure by myself and not just hope or expect it is O(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the function you're looking for is `zend_string_equal_val`, which is in https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_string.c. It's about 25 lines of assembly code.

For `in_array`, the code is in https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c. Look for `PHP_FUNCTION(in_array)`, which calls [`php_search_array`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L1524). It uses a macro `ZEND_HASH_FOREACH_KEY_VAL`, which I expect expands into a `for` loop that iterates over the array elements.